# How to scale the selected object only inside the canvas area in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I tried to drag and scale the object only inside the canvas area.

Now drag is working and how to make scaling also only inside the canvas area.

means i need to scale it only inside the canvas area bounds then it has to stop scaling after it crosses min and max length and width of the canvas.

please see this link [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ravikirana/h4cw2ejk/#)

js:

```
var canvas; 
    //window.newAnimation = function(){
       canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    //}

    window.print = function(){
      console.log(canvas.getActiveObject()); 
      //console.log(canvas.getObjects()); 
    };

    window.addRect = function(){
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      fill: 'red',
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
    });
        canvas.add(rect);

    }

    window.addCircle = function(){
        var circle = new fabric.Circle({
      radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100
    });
        canvas.add(circle);
    }

    window.deleteObject = function() {
            canvas.getActiveObject().remove();
    }  

    canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
        var obj = e.target;
        console.log("inside");
        console.log(obj.getBoundingRect());

         // if object is too big ignore
        if(obj.currentHeight > obj.canvas.height || obj.currentWidth > obj.canvas.width){
            return;
        }        
        obj.setCoords();        
        // top-left  corner
        if(obj.getBoundingRect().top < 0 || obj.getBoundingRect().left < 0){
            obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
            obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
            //console.log("11111     "+obj.top+"   "+obj.left);
        }
        // bot-right corner
        if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height  > obj.canvas.height || obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width  > obj.canvas.width){
            obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
            obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
            //console.log("22222b     "+obj.top+"   "+obj.left);
        }
});

canvas.on('object:scaling', function (e) {
        var obj = e.target;
        var obj = e.target;
    if(obj.getBoundingRect().height > obj.canvas.height || obj.getBoundingRect().width > obj.canvas.width){
        console.log("return");
        return;
    }        
    obj.setCoords();        
    // top-left  corner

    if(obj.getBoundingRect().top < 0){
        obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
        //obj.height=;
    }

    if(obj.getBoundingRect().left < 0){
        obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
        //obj.width=200;
        //return;
        obj.width=Math.max(obj.width,(obj.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width));;
    }

    if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height  > obj.canvas.height){
        obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
        //obj.height=;
    }

    if(obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width  > obj.canvas.width){
        obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
        //obj.width=;
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "only inside the canvas area" Do you mean, stop scaling object when they go outside the edge?, or stop scaling when the mouse goes outside? or something else.

Comment: yes need to stop scaling after mouse goes outside. means object width and height must be between 0 to canvas.height and canvas.width. like https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#constrain-area

Comment: Hi Blindman67 can you help me to resolve it.

Comment: I think this link will be solved your problem. This fiddle is not mine. Credit should be gone to owner. http://jsfiddle.net/jw1827fm/1/

Comment: Wasted many time to looking the decision. And this helped me:
https://jsfiddle.net/hq7gc0kd

Comment: it does not work in higher versions of fabric. Is there a new solution for this in a higher version like 4.2.0?